# Textual diff for .pdf files -- How does fugitive accomplish such a feat?

Tags: plugin-fugitive

In a fugitive `:Gstatus` buffer, I often press `=` on a filename. This toggles an inline diff, showing or hiding the changes made to that file. Interestingly, this also works on binary .pdf files, showing the differences in textual form.

I am unable to recreate this on my terminal, however. Suppose that the pdf was updated in the most recent commit. Running `git diff HEAD~ HEAD file.pdf` gives an uninformative `Binary files a/file.pdf and b/file.pdf differ.`

Which brings me to the question: how does fugitive show the diffs in textual form? In the end, I would like to recreate this and view the textual diffs between two pdfs.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how fugitive does it, but with git in general you can use [`.gitattributes`](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/gitattributes) and set special diff filters (for example, I use [`gron` for JSON](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/gitconfig#L86-L87))

Comment: I don't know the exact answer to your question, but `git diff --text` shows the differences of binary files in a pager (`git --no-pager` can be used to send the diff to stdout, although most likely this can mess up your terminal)

Comment: Didn't even know about the `=` mapping in `:Gstatus`, let alone pdf diff. Live and learn.

Comment: I found that with Windows' `cmd` with git installed, a textual diff is rendered, but in `wsl` I get the binary files message. Fugitive just executes a git diff in the shell (which in this case, is cmd). So this behavior is due to Windows and linux treating .pdf files differently, which is strange. Regardless, I learnt a few things from the comments :) Now, as this qn is no longer related with Fugitive or vim, shall I close this question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not directly related to vim

Comment: I haven’t gotten round to it yet (obviously), but I’ve been meaning to dig into the fugitive source code to find out *precisely* how it displays diffs, and I think questions about the fugitive source code *are* Vim related. Voting to keep open.